# How to group and transform properly using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML structure

```
`<root>
  <Data_Group>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Hours>10</Hours>
    <Tag>A</Tag>
  </Data_Group>
  <Data_Group>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Hours>20</Hours>
    <Tag>A</Tag>
  </Data_Group>
  <Data_Group>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Hours>20</Hours>
    <Tag>B</Tag>
  </Data_Group>
  <Data_Group>
    <ID>3456</ID>
    <Hours>20</Hours>
    <Tag>A</Tag>
  </Data_Group>
  <Data_Group>
    <ID>4567</ID>
    <Hours>50</Hours>
   <Tag>B</Tag>
  </Data_Group>
  <Pay_Data_Group>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Amount>200.00</Amount>
    <Amount2>50.00</Amount2>
  </Pay_Data_Group>
  <Pay_Data_Group>
    <ID>3456</ID>
    <Amount>250.00</Amount>
    <Amount2>1000.00</Amount2>
  </Pay_Data_Group>
</root>`
```

In the XML above, I have 2 separate groups of data and the only fields I want to read from the 'Pay_Data_Group' are the 'Amount' fields. I need to populate a value, example Converted_Hrs as below.

Example XSLT

```
<xsl:if test="Data_Group/ID = //Pay_Data_Group/ID">
<Converted_Hrs><xsl:value-of select="format-number((Amount div 8) *100,'000000')"/></Converted_Hrs>
</xsl:if>
```

This actually works when I only have 1 'data_group' and one 'pay_data_group' in the xml, but when I have more than 1 this fails.

I want to be able to check the entire file to see if 'ID' in the 'Data_Group' is the same in any of the 'Pay_Data_Group' and then extract the 'Amount' field.

I tried solving this using XSL keys, something like

```
<xsl:key name="Data_ID" match="Data_Group" use="ID"/>
<xsl:key name="Pay_Data_ID" match="root/Pay_Data_Group" use="ID"/>
```

and when these 2 keys match then generate the converted_hrs value. However that does not work.

```
<xsl:if test="$Data_ID = $Pay_Data_ID">
<Converted_Hrs><xsl:value-of select="format-number((Amount div 8) *100,'000000')"/></Converted_Hrs>
</xsl:if>
```

How can I read through the entire file to see if an ID exists in both the Data_Group and Pay_Data_Group and only then extract the amount?

Here's the existing grouping currently in use

<xsl:for-each-group select="Data_Group" group-by="concat(ID, Tag)">

This grouping allows be to group any ID's with the same TAG so I can report the hours according to the tag. The issue I have is how do I get the 'Amount' from 'Pay_Data_Group' into this grouping so I can pass the converted hrs in the final output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicated IDs in the `Data_Group` and the `Pay_Data_Group` elements itself I think you can simply group those two element types by `ID` and check whether your group has two items and only then output your `Amount`:

```
  <xsl:template match="/root">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Data_Group | Pay_Data_Group" group-by="ID">
            <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
                <Converted_Hrs><xsl:value-of select="format-number((current-group()/Amount div 8) *100,'000000')"/></Converted_Hrs>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I will have duplicated id values in the Data_Group, I was already grouping that by the ID and so was the trouble to get what's in the Pay_Data_Group.

Comment: @Vic, consider to edit the question with a representative input sample and the corresponding result sample you need.

Comment: I updated the question with extra details and sample, see if that make more sense now.

Comment: @Vic, where is the wanted result sample for that input sample? Anyway, I think your key from the original question e.g. `<xsl:key name="Pay_Data_ID" match="root/Pay_Data_Group" use="ID"/>` can be used for e.g. `<Converted_Hrs><xsl:value-of select="format-number(key('Pay_Data_ID', ID)/Amount div 8) *100,'000000')"/></Converted_Hrs>`. If you want to do that conditionally then use e.g. an `<xsl:if test="key('Pay_Data_ID', ID)">..</xsl:if>` wrapper.

Comment: missed reading your comment earlier but you're right, the Key approach I used earlier was working, I made a mistake the last time I tried using it and hence it didn't work, but I'm all set now! thank you for helping!